# How to render a page only once with multiple table data with no relations between them?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

How can I get both table (dept_db,role_db) data into my createUsers page. I want to render my page once so that the previous query remains. Thank you.

```
exports.createUsers = function (req, res, next) {

    model.dept_db.findAll().then(depts => {
        res.render('createUsers', { depts: depts });
     });
     model.role_db.findAll().then(roles => {
        res.render('createUsers', { roles: roles });
     });
    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain all the promises together using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
const deptPromise = model.dept_db.findAll();
const rolePromise = model.role_db.findAll();
Promise.all([deptPromise, rolePromise]).then(([depts, roles]) => {
  res.render('createUsers', {depts, roles});
});
```